# setting up postfix on Ubuntu with Apache and nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, postfix, email-server

I don't know how to ask this question because I've gone through hundreds of lines of configuration code.  I'm trying to setup a mail server on my Ubuntu box.  I found a tutorial here http://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/ which uses postfix, dovecot, mysql, php, apache.  I'm also running nginx so I had to find a tutorial on how to get the two servers working together.  I got to the point where the tutorial asks me to point my browser to https://mail.example.com/postfixadmin/setup.php but I get this error `The server at mail.example.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.`  Now I don't know where to look for the error or what configuration files to post here because if I posted them all this question would be 100 pages long.  Maybe someone can guide me in the direction of where to look?

Comment: They actually mean for you to use your own mailservername. Example.com is an example.

Comment: I do use my own server name.  I just put example.com here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The server at mail.example.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup
>   failed.

This indicates that there is no `A` or `CNAME` record in DNS for `mail.example.com`. You need to create that record and ensure that it's pointing to the IP of your server.